# Find window by class name

Tags: winapi, vb6

I want to close a certain window.

Spy++ tells me that the window is of class name "ad_win#2":

[image]

However, when I use FindWindow like that...

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "USER32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

 Dim lRet&
 lRet = FindWindow("ad_win#2", vbNullString)
```

.... lRet is 0, meaning that it didn't find any window.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: "ad_win#2" this is ansi or unicode string in vb6 ? `String` in vb6 - unicode or ansi mean ?

Comment: Is the window in question a child of another window? If so, find the parent window first, then use `FindWindowEx()` to find the child window.

Comment: @RemyLebeau How would I know?

Comment: I got it. I will post a solution.

Comment: @RbMm Your comment lead me to use GetClassName on that window handle and see what it produces. I could see that it had a ChrW(10) at the end of the name in VB6.

Comment: @tmighty "*How would I know?*" - Spy++ shows you the parent/child relationships. Once you use the dialog you are looking at to find a window and then press OK, Spy++ will show you the window in relation to other windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when I add a ChrW(10) to the name like this:

```
Dim lRet&
lRet = FindWindow("ad_win#2" & ChrW(10), vbNullString)
```